# AWS Gogs deployment using Docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy this [Docker Gogs image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/codeskyblue/docker-gogs/) to AWS.
It worked fine on my local Docker instance, but I get the following error on AWS:

```
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: github.com/gogits/gogs /goroot/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l: running gcc failed: Cannot allocate memory [0m2015/02/15 15:09:04 
The command [/bin/sh -c go get -v -tags sqlite] returned a non-zero code: 2. Check snapshot logs for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add more swapfile may help.

Add file `.ebextensions/01-commands.config`

```
container_commands:
    00001-add-swap:
        command: '[ -f /var/swap ] || (dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap bs=1M count=1024 && mkswap /var/swap && swapon /var/swap)'
```